Vivado and simulation for a 4-bit up counter
I am creating a 4-bit up counter using Verilog in Vivado.
For this counter, I would like to use flip-flops to represent each bits from Q0 to Q4.
For simplification, I used D flip flop to represent Q3, Q1, and Q0, and JK flip flop to represetn Q2.
However, I ran into a strange problem with Q3.
Long story short,
If using assign d3 = ~RESET & (Q[3] ^ (Q[2] & Q[1] & Q[0]));, the simnulation output looks perfect.
But If I use assign d3 = ~RESET & ((Q[3] & ((~Q[2]) + (~Q[1]) + (~Q[0]))) + ((~Q[3]) & Q[2] & Q[1] & Q[0])); or assign d3 = ~RESET & (Q[3] & (~Q[2] + ~Q[1] + ~Q[0]) + (~Q[3] & Q[2] & Q[1] & Q[0])); the output for D3 looks strange, see screenshots from simulation output at the bottom of this post.
However, the two latter cases are equivalent to the Q[3] XOR (Q[2] and Q[1] and Q[0]), so what is going on here?
The transition table is here for convience:

And here's the flip-flop transition table for Q3 to Q0:
My original plan was to use RS for Q3, and T for Q1, however, for troubleshooting purposes, I changed Q3 and Q1 to D flip flop, so please ignore R3 S3, and T1.

module Four_bits_Up_Counter(input CLK, RESET, output [3:0] Q);    
    wire d0, d1, d3; 
    //wire t1; 
    wire j2, k2;
    //wire r3, s3;
    
    D_FF D0 (.D(d0), .CLK(CLK), .Q(Q[0]));
    D_FF D1 (.D(d1), .CLK(CLK), .Q(Q[1]));
    //T_FF F1   (.T(t1), .CLK(CLK), .Q(Q[1]));    
    JK_FF JK2 (.J(j2), .K(k2), .CLK(CLK), .Q(Q[2]));
    //RS_FF RS3 (.R(r3), .S(s3), .CLK(CLK), .Q(Q[3]));
    D_FF D3 (.D(d3), .CLK(CLK), .Q(Q[3]));

    assign d0 = (~RESET) & (~Q[0]);
    
    assign d1 = ~RESET & (Q[1] ^ Q[0]);
    
    //assign t1 = (RESET & Q[1]) | (~RESET & Q[0]);
    
    assign j2 = (~RESET & Q[1] & Q[0]);
    assign k2 = (RESET | (Q[1] & Q[0]));
    
    //assign r3 = (RESET | (Q[2] & Q[1] & Q[0]));
    //assign s3 = ((~RESET) & Q[2] & Q[1] & Q[0]);
    //assign d3 = ~RESET & ((Q[3] & ((~Q[2]) + (~Q[1]) + (~Q[0]))) + ((~Q[3]) & Q[2] & Q[1] & Q[0])); // this doesn't work
    //assign d3 = ~RESET & (Q[3] & (~Q[2] + ~Q[1] + ~Q[0]) + (~Q[3] & Q[2] & Q[1] & Q[0]));     // this also does not work
    assign d3 = ~RESET & (Q[3] ^ (Q[2] & Q[1] & Q[0])); // this one works
endmodule


module D_FF(input CLK, D, output reg Q);
    always @ (posedge CLK)
        Q <= D;
endmodule
                               
module T_FF(input CLK, T, output reg Q);
    always @ (posedge CLK)
        Q <= (Q ^ T);     
endmodule

module JK_FF(input CLK, J, K, output reg Q);
    always @ (posedge CLK)
        Q <= (J & ~Q) | (~K & Q);
endmodule

module RS_FF(input CLK, R, S, output reg Q);
    always @ (posedge CLK)
        Q <= S | (Q & ~R);
endmodule

Test bench
module Four_bits_Up_Counter_TB();
    reg CLK;
    reg R;
    wire [3:0] Q;
    
    Four_bits_Up_Counter TB(.CLK(CLK), .RESET(R), .Q(Q));
    
    initial
        CLK = 0;
        always
            #5 CLK = ~CLK;
            
     initial
     begin
        R = 0;  
        #20;
        R = 1;
        #10;
        R = 0;
        #197;
        R = 1;
        #20;
        R = 0;
        #100;
        $finish;
     end
endmodule

Simulation output:
Workign D3:
assign d3 = ~RESET & (Q[3] ^ (Q[2] & Q[1] & Q[0])); // this one works
It counts upto 16

Not working D3:
assign d3 = ~RESET & ((Q[3] & ((~Q[2]) + (~Q[1]) + (~Q[0]))) + ((~Q[3]) & Q[2] & Q[1] & Q[0]));
It only counts upto 9

Not working D3:
assign d3 = ~RESET & (Q[3] & (~Q[2] + ~Q[1] + ~Q[0]) + (~Q[3] & Q[2] & Q[1] & Q[0]));
It only counts upto 7


I figured out the problem in my codes.
Insrtead of using +, I should have used | for or operation.
